# Union of Perfect Sets

Tags: general-topology

I know that the intersection of perfect sets is not perfect, because there exist counterexamples. But, is it true that the union of perfect sets is perfect? If not, then what are some counterexamples. If so, then can we prove this?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking about the union of two perfect sets, or are you asking about arbitrary unions of perfect sets?

Comment: @bof Arbitrary unions of perfect subsets of some metric space.

Comment: In the metric space $\mathbb R$ the closed interval $P_n=[\frac1n,2]$ is a perfect set for each $n\in\mathbb N,$ but the union $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}P_n=(0,2]$ is not perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy to show that the union of two (and thus of finitely many) perfect sets is perfect.
The union of a sequence of perfect sets might not be closed, e.g. if $E_n$ is a perfect set in $[1/(n+1), 1/n]$, $0$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_n E_n$.

Comment: How would we show/prove this then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the union of two closed sets is closed and if a point $p$ is a point of one of them which is not isolated, then $p$ is also a not isolated point of the union.

Comment: Thanks.Can you provide a proof for this?

Comment: @user19289 Of *what*? What was that I wrote that you feel that it is not proved?